# Magento 2 - Category filter on custom search page

Tags: magento2, product, category, collection, search

I have custom search page that is working perfectly and all the filters are applying properly except category filter.

Following is the code:

```
    $indices = $this->searchResult->getIndices();
    foreach ($indices as $index){
        if($index->getIdentifier() === "catalogsearch_fulltext") {
            $collection = $this->searchResult->getSearchCollection($index);

            //Apply filters if required
            $this->apiHelper->applyFilters($collection);

            $categoryRepository = $objectManager->create("\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository");
            $category = $categoryRepository->get(176,1);
            $collection->addCategoryFilter($category);

            if($this->request->getParam("category_id")) {
                //code for applying category filter
                $category_ids = [$this->request->getParam("category_id")];
                $collection->addCategoriesFilter(['in' => $category_ids]);
            }

            $collection->setPageSize($perPage);
            $collection->setCurPage($page);
            $size += $collection->getSize();
            foreach ($collection as $k => $product) {
                $result["products"][] = $this->apiHelper->createListProduct($product, $listProduct);
            }
        }
    }
```

where `$this->searchResult` is the instance of `\Mirasvit\Search\Block\Result`

after applying this code with category filter product collection return 0 items.

Any help, knowledge and experience sharing would be appreciated